# How to track users' activites on SP2013 social features?

Tags: site-usage, usage-counters, statistics

We have about 1,000 users in a SP2013 farm with 20+ site collections. All the social features (including blog, newsfeed, community site, etc) have been enabled. We would like to track the usage "user based". Hence we can see which partition of users don't like to use the system.

After some research, it seems I can enable audit report per site collection to collect statistics of visit, view, download, etc. For community sites (forum), there is existing statistic to see usesrs activities. However, I cannot find a way to collect the usage statistic on Newsfeed, @mention, #hashtag.

Could you give me suggestion? Thanks!